# What is Minecraft migration?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

1. What is the purpose of Migration?
2. I bought my Minecraft game today, do I still have to manually migrate?
3. Now let's say I already migrated, played the game... If I've done all of those things, will I lose the power of changing names if I migrate?

Comment: What do you mean by migrating?

Comment: What do you mean by professional answer? An answer that works in a bank or something?

Comment: no, a professional answer... Like, straight to the point.

Comment: shanodin, google minecraft migration

Comment: @Marla googling leads directly to: 1. [The Mojang account migration page](https://account.mojang.com/migrate) 2. [The Mojang Help page about account migration](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/775905-migrating-from-minecraft-to-mojang) 3. [The Mojang Help page about problems with account Migration](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/438361-account-migration-issues). If these are not clear enough, what exactly do you want?

Comment: @MrLemon  A professional answer.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the word "Professional". Asking for a professional answer pertaining to this question means "Give me an answer of the same standard as the Mojang support would give" cause that's what their profession is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very nice official answer to your question: https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/775905-migrating-from-minecraft-to-mojang

So to answer your question:

1. If you have an old Minecraft Account, you can migrate it into a Mojang Account, as it's easier to log in into Mojang.com and its other games like Scrolls and stuff.
2. No.
3. No.

Comment: Regarding 3: On the contrary, changing your user name is *not* possible with an old-style Minecraft account. You need the (migrated) Mojang account.

Comment: On the answer to number 2; So that means, if I buy a Minecraft account TODAY, minecraft will automatically migrate my account into a Mojang account?

Comment: Sort of. You can't buy a Minecraft account now, as when you buy the game you automatically create a Mojang account.

Comment: @Marla As ArceusMaster0493 mentioned, changing your username isn't possible with the old **Minecraft** account; rather, you need a **Mojang** account. This account will enable you to sign into all of Mojang's games with one account, rather than separate accounts for Minecraft, Scrolls, etc. With the Mojang account, you will be able to change your username every **30** days.

Comment: Press the tick button if you think this answered your question please :)